# Extension Method for copying properties form object to another, with first attempt

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, extension-methods

I'm trying to write an extension method that I can use to copy values from one object property to another object of a different type, as long as the property names and types match exactly.

This is what I have:

```
public static T CopyFrom<T>(this T toObject, object fromObject)
    {
        var fromObjectType = fromObject.GetType();
        var fromProperties = fromObjectType.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo toProperty in toObject.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            PropertyInfo fromProperty = fromObjectType.GetProperty(toProperty.Name);

            if (fromProperty != null) // match found
            {
                // check types
                var fromType = fromProperty.PropertyType.UnderlyingSystemType;
                var toType = toProperty.PropertyType.UnderlyingSystemType;

                if (toType.IsAssignableFrom(fromType))
                {
                    toProperty.SetValue(toObject, fromProperty.GetValue(fromObject, null), null);
                }
            }
        }

        return toObject;
    }
```

This is working great for non boxed types, but `Nullable<T>` returns false when I call

```
toType.IsAssignableFrom(fromType)
```

because its type is `Nullable<T>` and is not the underlying type `T`.

I read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789.aspx) that `GetType()` should unbox the `Nullable<T>` so it returns `T` but if I call that on `PropertyInfo.PropertyType` I get `ReflectedMemberInfo` and not the type `T` im looking for.

I think I'm missing something obvious here, so I thought I would throw it open to SO to get some advice.

Anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE: Here is the final method for anyone searching for this.

```
 public static T CopyFrom<T>(this T toObject, object fromObject)
    {
        var fromObjectType = fromObject.GetType();

        foreach (PropertyInfo toProperty in toObject.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            PropertyInfo fromProperty = fromObjectType.GetProperty(toProperty.Name);

            if (fromProperty != null) // match found
            {
                // check types
                var fromType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(fromProperty.PropertyType) ?? fromProperty.PropertyType;
                var toType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(toProperty.PropertyType) ?? toProperty.PropertyType;

                if (toType.IsAssignableFrom(fromType))
                {
                    toProperty.SetValue(toObject, fromProperty.GetValue(fromObject, null), null);
                }
            }
        }

        return toObject;
    }
```

Comment: What language are we in here?

Comment: C Sharp .Net, it uses extension method syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype.aspx).

For example:

```
toType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(toType) ?? toType;
```

Comment: So I have to know its a Nullable first right?
    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)) {…}

Comment: No, you don't.  `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` will return `null` if it's not nullable, so my code sample will work for all types.